# XML count elements, If id exists increment by one

Tags: php, xml

What i am trying to do is count the elements under the root element. Then check if one id on that same level has the id value. When this occurs it needs to increment by one.

**The code**

```
public function _generate_id()
{
    $id = 0;
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($this->_dom);
    do{
        $id++;
    } while($xpath->query("/*/*[@id=$id]"));

    return $id;
}
```

**example xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
    <book id="0">
        <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
        <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
        <genre>Computer</genre>
        <price>44.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
        <description>An in-depth look at creating applications
            with XML.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="1">
        <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
        <title>Midnight Rain</title>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
        <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies,
            an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen
            of the world.</description>
    </book>
</catalog>
```

Comment: I used a goto statement and increment the id and it seems to work. If someone has a better suggestion. I am always up for it.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry was so focused on making myself clear. Well i need to know hoe to count the elements and increment by one if the id is already taken. So the id needs to be unique. I do not care how it is done :P

Comment: I think I got it ;) Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following xpath query to get the maximum value of the id attribute:

```
$result = $xpath->query('/*/*[not(../*/@id > @id)]/@id');
```

In your function you can return this value incremented by `1`:

```
return intval($result->item(0)->nodeValue) + 1;
```

---

Update: You can do the increment operation using XPath as well. Note [`DOMXPath::evaluate()`](https://www.php.net/domxpath.evaluate):

```
return $xpath->evaluate('/*/*[not(../*/@id > @id)]/@id + 1');
                                                        |------- +1 in xpath
```

This will give you `2` - but as a double. I would suggest to convert to integer before returning the result:

```
return (integer) $xpath->evaluate('/*/*[not(../*/@id > @id)]/@id + 1');
```

Comment: This is the shortest code and it outputs what i want. That's why this is the excepted answer. Thank all for your time!

Comment: ... and it is a *pure* xpath solution ;)

Comment: @hakre :) Yep, I thought this too: the `+1` operation can be done with xpath as well.. had no time until now, will update the post when I have...

Comment: until then let's leave a link for the interested reader: http://php.net/domxpath.evaluate - also corrects my little mistake in a comment earlier :)

Comment: @hakre btw, you can update the post as well if you want. I would appreciate this!. If not, I'll delete this comment and do it myself later.... will be AFK again now... cu!

Comment: Also just seeing that user is only asking for quick codeZ to fill-up his library with he puts on youtube. You should remind him on credits if you ask me :) ref: https://github.com/Danoon/SimpleORM/commit/3e81da05d1f80a8030b41704988eed403cc4cc28

Comment: @hakre nice research :) ... However, thanks for `DOMXPath::evaluate()` !!! I didn't know this before :) Have updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create an array of all existing ID values first (which is a single xpath query) and then you check against it:

```
$id = 0;
while(isset($ids[$id])) {
    $id++;
}

echo $id; # 2
```

Creating such a list is trivial running the xpath on SimpleXML, however this can be easily ported to DOMXPath as well with `iterator_to_array`:

```
<?php
$buffer = <<<BUFFER
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
    <book id="0">
        <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
        <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
        <genre>Computer</genre>
        <price>44.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
        <description>An in-depth look at creating applications
            with XML.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="1">
        <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
        <title>Midnight Rain</title>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
        <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies,
            an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen
            of the world.</description>
    </book>
</catalog>
BUFFER;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer);
$ids = array_flip(array_map('intval', $xml->xpath("/*/*/@id")));
```

[Interactive Demo](http://eval.in/30722)

Additionally I suggest you to not use `0` (zero) as ID value.

Answer (score 1):

Use simplexml, try this

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($this->_dom);
$id = is_array($xml->book) ? $xml->book[count($xml->book)-1]->attributes()->id : 0;

return $id;
```